# Errors after changing package name

Tags: android, exception, android-intent, package

I am a new developer creating an app for the android play store

I changed my package name and project name for my final version so that I can upload to Google Play store. Although, final test on my app after changing this causes none on my intents to launch new activities to work. I get exceptions saying

> no activity found to handle intent {act=com.packagename.appname.MAIN }

and then the app closes after my splash activity finishes.

Whatever activity I launch with it works fine, but then when I press a button to launch a different activity via an intent method, it crashes.

It was working fine before I changed the package name so their must be something I am missing there.

Comment: did you change the package name in `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: If you use android studio, use the rename option, it should rename everything accordingly and you wouldn't have this issue.
Grep for the old package name in your project to see if it is still referenced somewhere.

Comment: i searched for all same package names and changed, i alos changed the package name in the manifest and all activies

Comment: Put the code of your intent callings.

Comment: i found the problem. i hadn't changed to package name in the manifest corectly. my error